# Regex add character before word

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
text = 'https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/meld/4376491/'
d = re.sub(r'(meld)', r'\1s', text)
e = re.sub(r'api',r'(/meld)', d)
print(e)
```

required solution : "https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/api/melds/4376491/tenant-files/"

Is there any solution to add the word api before the word melds.

Comment: your solution shows `melds` as opposed to `meld` in the input

Comment: I have added "s" to the url and I need to add api/ before the melds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try:

```
import re

text = 'https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/meld/4376491/'

e = re.sub(r'/meld', '/api/melds', text)

print(e)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/api/melds/4376491/
```

### Note:

If you want `tenant-files/` at the end, then

```
e = re.sub(r'/meld', '/api/melds', text) + "tenant-files/"
```

##### output:

```
https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/api/melds/4376491/tenant-files/
```

Comment: No problem - I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is here.

```py
import re
text = 'https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/meld/4376491/'
e = re.sub(r'(/meld)', r'/api\1s', text)
print(e)
```

output

```
https://app.propertymeld.com/1568/v/23256/api/melds/4376491/
```

Comment: That’s right. I fixed the regular expression.